# Not able to open PDF from Android app using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm using Delphi 10.4 for developing android mobile application. I need to open PDF in both online and local.

By using this code I can able to open the PDF which is online but not able to open the file from local.

```
procedure openPdf(InpStrPDFPath: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  LIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  LIntent.setDataAndType(StrToJURI(InpStrPDFPath), StringToJString('application/pdf'));
  SharedActivity.StartActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

And tried the following code:

```
procedure OpenPD_Local(InpStrPDFPath: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  LUri := StrToJURI(InpStrPDFPath);
  LIntent.SetDataAndType(LUri, StringToJString('application/pdf'));
  LIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

When I use the above code, it tries open the installed PDF reader but not able to open the file. Please provide me any suggestion to open the PDF file locally in android using Delphi.

Comment: Where is that local PDF file stored?

Comment: System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath + '/' +'1.pdf'

Comment: If you use StrToJURI you need to have Secure File Sharing checked in the Entitlements List in Project Options

Comment: Yeah. It was enabled.